# Enumerate graph recursively

Tags: c#, .net, recursion, enumeration

I have the following (concretes thereof):

```
public interface IDirectory
{
   IEnumerable<IDirectory> Directories{get;}
}
```

I build a graph *n* directories deep. Now I would like to enumerate the directories starting from the root and recursively to the terminal/deepest directories and I must do so in order, I.E. never return a directory before having returned it's parent.  I'm sure there is an elegant solution but it's getting late in my timezone and my grey matter is getting tired so any pointers very much appreciated.

Comment: So if you had directory1, which contained file1, file2, and directory2, you would want the 'visit' order to be  directory1, directory1\file1, directory1\file2, directory1\directory2?

Comment: No, just want to enumerate the directories..should remove the files prop, misleading, sorry..

Comment: Breadth first or depth first?

Comment: Is this a general directed graph, or just a tree?

Comment: It's just a tree, in this case representing a file system

Comment: That's to hard links a file system isn't necessarily a tree. And if you are really perverse it' isn't even acyclic. I used to have a mount point of drive `C:` inside itself. Windows search was not amused :) http://xkcd.com/981

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The two other solutions are typical recursive solutions to this problem, and are suitable for shallow graphs with no cycles. If you have a deep graph with cycles, these aren't going to work well. You'll be better off with something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> DepthFirstTraversal<T>(
    T root, 
    Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> children)
{
    var set = new HashSet<T>();
    var stack = new Stack<T>();
    stack.Push(root);
    while(stack.Count != 0)
    {
        T current = stack.Pop();
        if (set.Contains(current)) continue;
        yield return current;
        set.Add(current);
        foreach(var child in children(current))
            stack.Push(child);
    }
}
```

and then call it with

```
foreach(var d in DepthFirstTraversal(root, x=>x.Directories))
   ...
```

The set keeps track of nodes visited already, and so takes up O(n) space. There's no recursion, so it is O(1) in stack space.

If you know there are no cycles you can eliminate the set and save on that cost.

Comment: This solution can also easily be adapted to breadth-first, just replace the stack with a queue.

Comment: Small nitpick: You still need the set in a DAG if you want to avoid visiting nodes twice. You can only eliminate it in a tree.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Good point. If you visit nodes repeatedly in a DAG the algorithm can be be O(m^n) in time instead of O(n); if you visit nodes repeatedly in a graph with cycles then it doesn't terminate at all! On the other hand, in immutable persistent trees sometimes you *want* to visit the same node twice because they are *logically* different nodes even if they are *referentially* identical.

Answer (score 4):

```
IEnumerable<IDirectory> Enumerate(IDirectory parent)
{
    yield return parent;
    foreach (var child in parent.Directories)
        foreach (var directory in Enumerate(child))
            yield return directory;
}
```

Not the most efficient, but it works.  Eric Lippert has written a few items about how you could do this more efficiently (but less concisely) using a `Stack<IDirectory>` instead of recursive method calls.

Comment: Great, that will do me for now, thanks. Will look at Mr Lippert's Stack solution later.

Comment: @MylesMcDonnell I just found the first blog post of Eric's that I read on this topic: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/12/19/immutability-in-c-part-seven-more-on-binary-trees.aspx.  If I recall correctly, he has also written about it on this site.

Answer (score 4):

Shorter version:

```
IEnumerable<IDirectory> Enumerate(IDirectory parent)
{
    return new[] { parent }.Concat(parent.Directories.SelectMany(Enumerate));
}
```

**Warning:** This solution (as well as the other one posted) does *not* guard against infinite loops. It is theoretically possible to have a circular reference in your object structure, in which case this will simply go on forever and never stop.

Comment: I like! I will remember this pattern.

Comment: Also note that it is O(n h) where n is the number of nodes in the graph and h is the length of the longest path from root to leaf. Since h can be anywhere from 1 to n (and is typically log n base the branching factor) this means that this algorithm, though pleasantly short, is typically O(n log n) and worst case O(n^2) in time, and O(h) in stack space, and O(1) in heap space. A better algorithm is O(n) in time, O(1) in stack space and O(h) in heap space.